# javascript - validate nested json object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following json schema.

```
const myJson = {
    "type": "typeName"
    "firstName": "Steven",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "address": {
        "primary": {
            "city": "abc",
            "street": {
                "name": {
                    "subName": "someName"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to loop over each of the properties for required validation on this json, I have the following code so far which works if the property in the json is not nested.

```
let errors = [];
const typeName = ['firstName', 'lastName'],
const typeAttr = Object.keys(myJson);

typeName.forEach(attr => {
  if (!typeAttr.includes(attr)) {
    errors.push(`Missing field: ${attr}`);
  }
});
```

How can I add the nested json property like `primary`, `city`, `street` and validate the way I have done it.

Comment: I’m having hard time to understand your question, could you explain what do you mean by adding nested properties (you’re doing validation)

Comment: Do you mean you need to validate the json deeply?

Comment: @RazLuvaton thats right....

Comment: How the `typeName` will look like? `address.primary`?

Comment: I am totally open to restructure the above code, my code only works without nested properties.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236199/discussion-between-raz-luvaton-and-user2281858).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can check nested properties on json object

```
const myJson = {
  type: "typeName",
  firstName: "Steven",
  lastName: "Smith",
  address: {
    primary: {
      city: "abc",
      street: {
        name: {
          subName: "someName",
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

let errors = [];
const typeName = ["firstName", "lastName", "address.primary", "address.primary.city"];

function checkNested(obj, level, ...rest) {
  if (obj === undefined) return false;
  if (rest.length == 0 && obj.hasOwnProperty(level)) return true;
  return checkNested(obj[level], ...rest);
}

typeName.forEach((attr) => {
  let props = attr.split(".");
  if (!checkNested(myJson, ...props)) {
    errors.push(`Missing field: ${attr}`);
  }
});

console.log(errors);
```

For reference on how to check Nested properties you can check this answer.
[Test for existence of nested JavaScript object key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/test-for-existence-of-nested-javascript-object-key)

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this. This method gives whether the data is having all the provided keys or not i.e., will return either `true` or `false`

```js
let obj = {"type":"typeName","firstName":"Steven","lastName":"Smith","address":{"primary":{"city":"abc","street":{"name":{"subName":"someName"}}}}};

const typeName = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'address', 'address.primary', 'address.primary.city', 'address.primary.street'];

const validate = (data, types) => {
  return types.every(type => {
    // Split the keys using `.`
    const keys = type.split('.');
    // Check if the length is more than 1, 
    // if yes, then we need to check deeply
    if (keys.length > 1) {
      let datum = {
        ...data
      };
      // Check through all the keys found using split 
      for (let key of keys) {
        // if any key is not found or falsy then return false
        if (!datum[key]) {
          return false;
        }
        datum = datum[key];
      }
      return true;
    } else {
      // if the length of the keys is not more than 1 then it means
      // the key is at the top level and return the value as boolean
      return !!data[type]
    }
  })
}

console.log(validate(obj, typeName));

console.log(validate(obj, ['firstName', 'lastName', 'address', 'address.primary', 'address.primary.zip']));
```

This below method will return the keys that were not present in the provided data

```js
const validate = (data, types) => {
  let errors = [];
  types.forEach(type => {
    const keys = type.split('.');
    let datum = {
      ...data
    };
    // Loop through the keys 
    for (let [index, key] of keys.entries()) {
    // Check if the key is not available in the data
    // then push the corresponding key to the errors array
    // and break the loop
      if (!datum[key]) {
        errors.push(keys.slice(0, index + 1).join('.'));
        break;
      }
      datum = datum[key];
    }
  })
  return errors;
}

const obj = {"type":"typeName","firstName":"Steven","lastName":"Smith","address":{"primary":{"city":"abc","street":{"name":{"subName":"someName"}}}}};

const typeName = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'address', 'address.primary', 'address.primary.city', 'address.primary.street'];
console.log(validate(obj, ['firstName', 'lastName']));
console.log(validate(obj, ['firstName', 'lastName', 'address', 'address.primary', 'address.primary.zip']));
console.log(validate(obj, [...typeName, 'test', 'address.primary.zip', 'address.test.zip']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/), a proposed IETF standard with tons of library [implementations](https://json-schema.org/implementations.html) available for several languages for describing, generating, and validating JSON documents.

To require your JSON to have all the properties be present, you'll need a JSON Schema like below.

```
let typeNameSchema = {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "$id": "https://example.com/typename.schema.json",
  "title": "Type Name",
  "description": "A person's name and address details",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "firstName",
    "lastName",
    "address"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "type": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "address": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "primary"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "primary": {
          "type": "object",
          "required": [
            "city",
            "street"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "city": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "street": {
              "type": "object",
              "required": [
                "name"
              ],
              "properties": {
                "name": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "required": [
                    "subName"
                  ],
                  "properties": {
                    "subName": {
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then use any library to validate your JSON data against the above schema. [jsonschema](https://github.com/tdegrunt/jsonschema) is one of the most popular JSON Schema validators for JavaScript. Here's how to validate your `myJson` data against the above `typeNameSchema`.

```
const Validator = require('jsonschema').Validator;
const validator = new Validator();

console.log(validator.validate(myJson, typeNameSchema)); // result
```

Validation results will be returned in a `ValidatorResult` object with the most important properties `valid` of type `boolean` and `errors` of type `ValidationError[]`. `ValidationError` object will have the `property` name and error `message`.